# I need help setting up .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to set up .htaccess. If the user clicks the "site.com/profile" link, I need to check if there is a "token" field in the user's cookies. If this field is not empty, I must let the user through, otherwise I redirect them to the "site.com/login" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|;)?token=[^;]+(;|$)
RewriteRule ^ /login [R=302,L]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server. It generally is a good idea to implement such rule in the http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can also use a distributed configuration file (often called ".htaccess"), but the consideration of such files needs to be enabled first and their usage comes with a number of disadvantages.